# What is a reasonable notice period to quit a *contract* job, if you are a developer?

Tags: united-states, notice-period, quitting

I have recently had this issue. I myself was not sure but gave one week of notice. I think I did the right thing. By giving a two week notice, I would created uncertain environment for two weeks instead of one week. I **am looking for a better answer, from which I can learn**. What the appropriate notice is when it is not defined in the contract and why is that appropriate over a longer or shorter notice period? What impact it may have on my work environment. My focus is on **contract** job only.  If you would like to add about perm job, that are welcome as well. Thanks

Comment: Normally, notice periods would be spelled out in the contract that you sign.  If your contract didn't spell that out, the appropriate notice period will generally be dependent at least on where you are (customs in the US are different from those in India, for example).  In general, whatever the customary notice period for a permanent job would be a reasonable starting point if the contract is silent.

Comment: Lets talk about US only :)

Comment: What does your contract say that is the "reasonable" notice by definition.

Comment: I have to look up my contract which I have to find first. I have raised a couple of concerns in my  question and wanted to clarify that. Let me add this that we are 7 members in IT team.

Answer (score 3):

In my last contract position I was given 2 weeks notice. If you are terminating under good terms, it is better to have a couple of weeks to make sure tasks are either wrapped up, hand offs are done and other basic things are handled.

> By giving a two week notice, I would created uncertain environment for
>   two weeks instead of one week.

No, in giving notice you secure the end point and then work toward it. I'm not sure I see how this is an *uncertain environment* for two weeks instead of one unless you have some condition that makes you not regularly come to work or something. If a person regularly goes to work and works their time then this gives clarity as to how long is that person around and what is needed before that person moves on to the next contract. What is uncertain during that final week or two?

Answer (score -1):

Notice is usually specified in contracts, usually when I'm a team lead, I would like to receive notice as soon as possible since depending on role, location and company it can take weeks if not months to interview and hire new person.